# Mapping from one isometric surface to another

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, isometry

Consider the “pacman” region M given by $\textbf{x}(u,v)=(u\cos(v),u\sin(v),0), 0 \leq u \leq R, 0 \leq v \leq V$ , with $V < 2\pi$. Let $c = V/2\pi$. Let M* be given by the parametrization
$\textbf{x*}(u,v)=(cu\cos(v/c),cu\sin(v/c),\sqrt{1-c^2}u)$

Compute that $E = E^{*}$ , $F=F^{*}$ , $G=G^{*}$, and conclude that the mapping $\textbf{f}=\textbf{x*} \circ \textbf{x}^{-1}: M\rightarrow M*$ is a local isometry. Describe this mapping in concrete geometric terms.

I had no problem computing E,F,G etc. and showing that but I'm struggling with the idea of $\textbf{x}^{-1}$ and that final mapping/function.

[edit] After a comment instructed me to draw the images of $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{x*}$ I see that M and M* are an incomplete circle (hence pacman) and an incomplete cone respectively. However, I'm still not quite sure how to approach the idea of the inverse and thus the mapping from one surface to the other.

Comment: This looks like a very familiar homework problem. Why don't you start by drawing pictures of the *images* of $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf x^*$? Edit your question with the answers to this.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin, I see now that they are an incomplete circle and an incomplete cone respectively, but I'm still not sure how to approach the idea of the inverse of $\textbf{x}$ and the function from x to x*.

Comment: Well, what do you mean by incomplete cone? Can you be more precise? How do you associate points of the pacman region (your "incomplete" disk) to points of the cone? That's precisely what $\mathbf f$ does.

Comment: By incomplete cone I mean a cone that isn’t fully revolved around the z-axis. The points from the Pac-Man region seem to be raised up the z-axis by an amount proportional to u. I’m just not sure how to calculate the function f (or if I have to calculate it exactly).

Comment: No, it *is* completely rotated about the $z$-axis. Work out the geometry from the trig/algebra. The equation is very carefully constructed, so you must pay attention to every detail.

Comment: Ah, I see that now, thank you. However, I'm still not quite sure on the steps/process for creating an explicit function for the mapping from M to M*, though I feel I understand it visually/conceptually better now.

Comment: What the author (i.e., I) was looking for was an actual physical/geometric description. You already have formulas. Pay attention to what happens to the points in pacman with $v=0$ and with $v=V$.